# open popup inline when the page is loaded with pagemagnific-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

i have tried the [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) for open a simple popup inline when the webpage is ready but not work (but if i generate a link and i click it work!).
Can anyone help me?

this is the code (library and jquery are included):

```
  // class of popup
 .white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

// INLINE POPUP
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">HELLO!</div

// if click it the popup work
<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Show inline popup</a>

// this it should open the popup when the page is loaded
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({type:'inline', midClick: true });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. With the code above you've successfully *initialized* the element, now you're going to want to take a look at the [Magnific Popup Public Methods](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#public-methods), specifically `.open`.

Add this to the end of your initilization script: `.magnificPopup('open');`

All together:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({type:'inline', midClick: true });
}).magnificPopup('open');
</script>
```

That should do it for you! :)